# How to substitute array values for Octopus AWS Lambda functions

Tags: aws-lambda, octopus-deploy, octopus

Consider the following

```
{
 "foo": [ "cat", "dog" ] 
}
```

I want to replace these values in Octopus with

```
{
 "foo": [ "wolf" ] 
}
```

How do I do it with Octopus? I can't replace with ["wolf"] in the value as I receive an error: `Invalid JSON: Expecting ','`.

I'm using dotnet core.

Answer (score 0):

How are you replacing the variable value?

This should be possible using [Structured Configuration Variables](https://octopus.com/docs/projects/steps/configuration-features/structured-configuration-variables-feature#StructuredConfigurationVariablesFeature-Arrayvariables) with a variable named `foo` set to `["wolf"]`.